# ubuntu is taking too much time to boot

Tags: boot, 17.10

my Ubuntu 17.10 is taking too much time to boot lots of people are having the same problem but i don't see a proper answer.

why nmbd.service is taking 1 min to start ?

here is the result of `sudo systemd-analyze blame`

```
     1min 1.679s nmbd.service
     16.662s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     15.172s dev-sda2.device
     13.391s apparmor.service
      9.423s snapd.service
      8.600s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      7.266s postfix@-.service
      7.209s udisks2.service
      6.632s mysql.service
      6.579s accounts-daemon.service
      6.566s NetworkManager.service
      6.232s ModemManager.service
      4.965s apport.service
      4.785s teamviewerd.service
      4.484s networking.service
      4.325s speech-dispatcher.service
      3.912s rsyslog.service
      3.742s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      3.663s gpu-manager.service
      3.306s systemd-rfkill.service
      3.031s avahi-daemon.service
      3.023s fwupd.service
      2.762s polkit.service
      2.524s virtualbox.service
      2.384s grub-common.service
      1.723s dev-loop2.device
      1.683s dev-loop0.device
      1.669s binfmt-support.service
      1.649s console-setup.service
      1.573s systemd-timesyncd.service
      1.512s winbind.service
      1.459s dev-loop1.device
      1.394s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.253s smbd.service
      1.234s thermald.service
      1.108s systemd-udevd.service
      1.103s packagekit.service
      1.093s dns-clean.service
      1.065s resolvconf.service
      1.048s upower.service
      1.047s systemd-random-seed.service
      1.025s systemd-modules-load.service
       919ms keyboard-setup.service
       884ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
       678ms systemd-logind.service
       663ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       642ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       587ms gdm.service
       532ms pppd-dns.service
       521ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       478ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       466ms systemd-journald.service
       411ms systemd-resolved.service
       364ms snap-core-3247.mount
       319ms wpa_supplicant.service
       288ms hddtemp.service
       275ms kerneloops.service
       274ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       263ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       240ms snap-core-3440.mount
       230ms dev-hugepages.mount
       192ms user@1000.service
```

**how can i fix this ?**

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  nmbd is really old (netbios over ip) and is used by samba to provide older protocols. I don't know if it can be disabled by using later protocols only. However the reason for the slow startup may have nothing to do with your machine. Back when I used Samba/cifs, my startups were slowed by my NASD devices that powered down after 15mins of inactivity; meaning they took awhile to spin up their drives & respond - ie. your network devices could be at fault too.  For me I stopped having them autoload; and only mount when I backup to them.

Comment: "lots of people are having the same problem"? A source on that would be helpful.